# Omit helper odd behaviour converting all props to any and not throwing expected errors

Tags: typescript

Here is code showing what is happening with comments on what I was hoping to achieve

```js
/*******************
 * First Situation *
 *******************/

type DefaultContext = Record<string, any>;

const logger = (str?: string | Record<string, unknown> | any[]) =>
  console.log(str);

interface Context<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>
  extends DefaultContext {
  one?: T;
  many?: T[];
}

function oldProcess<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
>(context: Context<T>) {
  const many = context.many; // T[] | undefined
  logger(many);

  const one = context.one; // T | undefined
  logger(one);
}

type BadContext<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> =
  Omit<Context<T>, "one">;

function badProcess<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
>(context: BadContext<T>) {
  const many = context.many; // expected `T[] | undefined` received `any`
  logger(many);

  const one = context.one; // expected error received `any` ❌
  logger(one); // expected error ❌
}

type AsiContext<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> =
  Context<T> & { one: never };

function asiProcess<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
>(context: AsiContext<T>) {
  const many = context.many; // T[] | undefined
  logger(many);

  const one = context.one; // never 
  logger(one); // want error ❌
}

/********************
 * Second Situation *
 ********************/

type NodeObj = Record<string, unknown> & {
  uid?: string;
  type?: string;
};

type Entity<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> =
  NodeObj &
    T & {
      changed?: string;
      created?: string;
    };

type TArgs<E extends Entity = Entity> = Partial<E> & { uids?: string[] };
const foo: TArgs = {
  uid: undefined,
  type: "User",
  uids: ["0x2a", "0x2b"],
};

// Create a new Type that should keep TArgs typed but Omit `uid`
type BadTArgs<T extends TArgs = TArgs> = Omit<T & { uids: string[] }, "uid">;
const bar: BadTArgs = {
  uid: 42, // expected error as prop is now omitted ❌
  type: 42, // expected error as prop should be `string` ❌
  uids: 42, // expected error as ids should be `string[]` ❌
};

// Create a new Type that should keep TArgs typed but force `uid` to be `never`
type AsiTArgs<T extends TArgs = TArgs> = T & { uids: string[] } & {
  uid?: never;
};
const baz: AsiTArgs = {
  uid: undefined, // want error ❌
  type: "User", // ✅
  uids: ["0x1", "0x2"], // ✅
};

const fooType = foo.type; // string | undefined ✅
const barType = bar.type; // unknown ❌
const bazType = baz.type; // string | undefined ✅

const fooUid = foo.uid; // string | undefined ✅
const barUid = bar.uid; // unknown  ❌ expected error
const bazUid = baz.uid; // undefined ❌ expected never
```

[TypeScript Playground with v4.9.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AYQPYDtgQA9goBeKAJQgGMsAnAEwB4BnYWgSxwHMAaKRHCAB8AKBE0crKKixcuEWqSgAKVrQD8ALihrOXKAB8K1Ok13c+yHAGscWAO44hh-oIDaAXQCUpZxOZYqBAAdDJcqmxeYpz4tEhU0Nh4hMCMACpQKRA49MzGNAwsbHqWNnaOzmSUBWbFFlBWtg5Ozlk5eXBIaJi4+ERQAN4iUFC4EFpQacNQALYCIBNpniIAvmLwVlTA7LijqPQACrRYCczM6ZlE2bn5pkUc9Y3lTkrVd+a8DWXNQkLKEn1gNokoD0kIfEMRv5iHNBEoASlgrCQFAAPSoyaeFxWegITgQejTMLyWjKZFRabQ0Y4aBkBFEYJjNEYjJGHF4mmEkbEhTKMZRNYiUCQKAAIUQ9BBKQubRub0KH1KTQqrxMCrqnyeP0qUAA8jN2KkpUQwXwAORjM2iEQbHBbHY4KAAIwlRxOEDOMqu7Vu6oemu+Kqqatq-qVz1+-16KW04sl0ZNaXBg0puCkyPhCeASPmzMukC2BKgAAMlh5sTkOQTi1BaNQIOwAG5F4vzYtE2QksnzClQtPEJl0rOMml5wgF-D0TK0Y6KOsJJstttQQAy5B25Lz+WOCBOiwpZ6vVmJhdAAILMdjG1IZWV5eWhkpfZUvYM1e6PrUVHVXsFQABkgzUhA2g0s2iiCra9q7IgF5uqc5w3t6cohu+jyBi+voPmhz6RvSQJQOel5ZmCEKppIMK5kOyQMhm6KYuWbKVvA+JctIna8uSYh9uRQGZtR2ZMnRoEKFAgC8G4ACHvrl2W50fYAjEPudCHoKqIAFTqRpmlaVpwyqVAADKJg5AZhrIIg2y7KpunaTZ2mose4DQAAclguK6k6ABWqpvoqT4Rv+KYjMg7D0BMHwANzTCeYUapFgonlAACieCGiAXr4D696oQGOHee8GrhtqSguW5nkBRkAGQlAVAABYCPIoXaBFlJ1uZBIxf6cUOSKaSnrQXDnIllwZTcyXbKAShjalOoHIgtDbIgqCMIlziVQ0IXMB1ehYmsVLwFgWDaL1-V5GQVXBfQ2jssxnI8FFjnaGaACqzAKGad1BRt2huGaAAMBAAEyIO9UB-YDTpmh4d0qRiGCtfg-BQDS9iTI5UDAHVxDMDVWBoFO1gQBAYCTH1A3o45U5OsgxD6oaJYXe2CVxsdA3pdceQs6dJMnTqtPXgFAzrbkTUajt5oXVa4j9s6c2xhKnNKOdIXaAALADfB0eO1CTtOB4wVAYDHMT7B5OUowGsAOtriMJ6q+r267lOimKPrhtYMT2O4-szrQMWHw1tbQvMHbGsYlrhZOzOSn6xtOg43jPslh8ngB0eIh0XDEBtYjyOoyKGPmXHXv44TxMKyelPU1A+20Ak9MhTWwBYInxbCbQjNo4RnNsz6CtkJzOoVYBF3BzoovlisAtCxMbdQLt0sugAXtoXek1zSuXV8uI3QSodQHJeC60pge26DL1vXvgCg5NMI-fWDACMINgwDkNX2ne0HWkaNkPtWDBAldEPgVm3ixKA18qQuloF-EUZBIH-zRnRT8jo1wQMQIvaBtIZaL3gSKQBGpgFVinNfKWPFf5PRCkoX+wQLp5iAYxEBnIwEkKkJA8hU5YFzWoRQxB6ERgrnzNrPcUdaDMOIEvNhSgl5cKnDwhhRZ+Hhx1m3EQQA)

To try and explain this with words...

1. In the `First Situation` I am adding a new type `BadContext` or `AsiContext` that utilized an already built-in `Context`. What I am needing the new type to do is remove the `one` prop.

   It sounds easy enough. However, `Context` accepts a generic input and that shoule be also passable through my new type as a generic input as well.

   `BadContext` IMO should do what I want it to do, but it is not doing that at all.
   Instead using the `Omit` wrapper around the `Context` is making all properties then `any` **abd it is still allowing the ommitted prop?**

   Alternatively, I came up with `AsiContext` and merge it with a `never` type. This does keep the existing types of the properties, but it does not throw errors like I would hope when passing the `one` variable with type `never` to a function that shouldn't from my understanding accept `never`
2. In the `Second Situation` I am somewhat similarly to the first situation, needing to remove an existing prop `uid` from the type, still allow generic passthrough, and also make prop `uids` be required.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpx0am) work for the first situation?

Comment: And [this one](https://tsplay.dev/m3vBjN) for the second situation?